# Extract score for an Application Hash using Virustotal and Python

Tags: python, json, sha

I am trying to get the score for Application hash and IP address using VirusTotal API.

The code works fine for IP address. See the code below:

```
###### Code starts 
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/ip-address/report'
parameters = {'ip': '90.156.201.27', 'apikey': 'apikey'}

response = urllib.request.urlopen('%s?%s' % (url, urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters))).read()
response_dict = json.loads(response)
#### Code ends
```

But the same does not work for Application Hash. Has anyone worked on this before:

For example, the Application Hash " f67ce4cdea7425cfcb0f4f4a309b0adc9e9b28e0b63ce51cc346771efa34c1e3" has a score of 29/67. [See the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TMdh.png) Has anyone worked on this API to get the score.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try the same with **requests** module in python library

```
import requests
params = {'apikey': '<your api key>', 'resource':<your hash>}
headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate","User-Agent" : "gzip,  My Python 
requests library example client or username"}
response_dict={}
try:
    response_dict = requests.get('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report', 
     params=params).json()

except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And you can use this to get the data:

```
if response_dict.get("response_code") != None and response_dict.get("response_code") > 0:
        # Hashes
        sample_info["md5"] = response_dict.get("md5")
        # AV matches
        sample_info["positives"] = response_dict.get("positives")
        sample_info["total"] = response_dict.get("total")
        print(sample_info["md5"]+" Positives: "+str(sample_info["positives"])+"Total "+str(sample_info["total"]))
    else:
        print("Not Found in VT")
```

For reference check [virustotalapi](https://github.com/ajaykumarkk/virustotal_apiclient) which lets you use multiple api keys simultaneously.